# Why is certain Collectors in Java stream API called downstream collector?

Tags: java, java-8

I wanted to know why we classify certain collectors as "downstream"? Is there an upstream Collector then? Please note that this is not about usage, but trying to understand the logic behind the term "downstream". To me, when you normally deal with stream API usage, all streams down the builder chain looks like they are downstream only.

```
List<String> list = List.of("AAA","B","CCCCC","DDD", "FFFFFF", "AAA");
List<Integer> res =
            list.stream()
                    .collect(
                            Collectors.mapping(s -> s.length(), // string -> int
                                Collectors.toList())); // downstreaming
```

In the above code, `Collectors.toList()` is regarded as downstream.

Comment: Note that "downstream" is a characteristic of _the position_, not an inherent quality of the collector itself.

Comment: method Collectors.mapping(..) is taking 2 arguments (one of them is a Collector) and returning a Collector, think on this like a Function Composition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term *downstream* in the documentation refers to one Collector accepting a second Collector as an argument. The argument is applied downstream (after) the Collector that accepts it. In other words, the downstream Collector is applied to the result of the upstream Collector.

In your example, `Collectors.toList` is downstream from `Collectors.mapping`.

Answer (score 9):

I often imagine the stream API as building a production line of a product. There are raw materials coming from somewhere (`ArrayList.stream`, `IntStream.range`, `Stream.of`, whatever), on a conveyer belt, and then with intermediate methods, the materials get transformed (`map`/`flatMap` etc) and filtered (`filter`/`limit` etc) and finally they reach the end of the line, where they get assembled into one final product (`collect`)<sup>*</sup>.

`Collector`s are "machines" that build different final products aforementioned. `toList` builds a list. `toSet` builds a `Set` etc. However, other collectors doesn't *fully* build the big thing, e.g. `groupingBy`. `groupingBy` only groups the materials by a key, and then spits the items out again, as groups, back on the conveyor belt. These collectors need another collector *down the production line* (aka down the stream) to continue building the final product.

`mapping` is another one of those collectors that doesn't completely build the final product. It merely transforms the materials and spits them out again, which is kind of like `map`. It's usefulness comes when you want to, e.g. transform the groups spitted out from a `groupingBy`. i.e. It's mostly useful when you use it as the downstream of another collector.

> Is there an upstream Collector then?

Following the production line analogy, the relationship is two way: `toList` is the downstream of `mapping`, so `mapping` is the upstream of `toList`. In official documentation though. This word isn't mentioned much. I only found it in [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)).

<sup>*</sup>There are other terminal operations, but let's focus on `collect`, since this is what the question is about.